# About ArrayList and Generic Type

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans, generic-type-argument

**1. First**: What is the difference between

```
ArrayList<Class> myList = new ArrayList<Class>();
ArrayList<Class> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**2. Second:**

If i declare myList like this:

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Why this still work: `myList.add("A String!!");`

but **NOT** work with this declaration:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I mean ArrayList myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: sorry for my carelessness @Eran

Answer (score 0):

**To your first question:**

> What is the difference between
>
> ```
> ArrayList<Class> myList = new ArrayList<Class>();
> ArrayList<Class> myList = new ArrayList<>();
> ```

There is no difference. In the second case, you let the compiler through [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) decide the type.

**To your second question:**

> If I declare myList like this:
>
> ```
> ArrayList myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
> ```
>
> Why this still work: `myList.add("A String!!");`
>
> but **NOT** work with this declaration:
>
> ```
> ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
> ```

[You are using a raw type in the first case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). This is kind of like using `Object` as generic type, only worse. You forego all compile-time type checking and thus you will encounter an `Exception` in your example.

Comment: There is no angle bracket after ArrayList in my question!!
It should be: ArrayList test = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: I updated my answer. Does this answer your question?

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
i declared ArrayList<> is it raw type??

Comment: No. `ArrayList myList = ...` is a raw type. Please check the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the first two. The second one is short version of the first one added in java 7 (I think)

In the second thing you declare a generic java list (the declaration doesn't say it is integer list). Then you give that variable an instance of ArrayList. This is something you do runtie and is not in the declaration. That's why the code compiles (you can add a string because the instance of array list can be anything). But it will fail at runtime because in that current run the instance is list of Integers.

When you declare it ArrayList myList then it knows compile time that this list can have only integers and compilation fails.